# What is the CSS clear style and how is it used?

Tags: css

What does the following do:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

and how is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's made to avoid float elements to keep on [floating](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp) after this div. In my opinion using this is a bad idea and it's better to use a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) on the wrapping div containing the floating elements.

Answer (score 7):

It will 'clear' any floated elements that appear above it in the HTML source. If you have floated elements within a container element, the container will have a height of 0 and the floated elements will 'spill out'. Clearing them will allow the container to assume the correct height.

[See here for a much better explanation](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

Comment: Using the overflow or float nearly everything (FnE - http://orderedlist.com/articles/clearing-floats-the-fne-method) method is probably the cleanest methods of clearing floats.

Comment: I agree, there are certainly better methods of doing this, but I think Alex was just after an explanation of the div method mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have `float` elements, a `clear:both` will not wrap around them, but will be displayed after them. In a way, this resets floating.
`clear:both` is also useful for giving an element the height of its floating children - without it the element would be smaller than its children, which is unattractive.

A less common use it to fix IE6 problems, where it doesn't display the page properly. Sometimes elements are rendered behind the background color, and clear:both can fix it.